# Commercially available material with highest density to cost ratio?

Tags: mass, atoms, density, molecules, elements

What are the top 5 commercially available materials (not limited to just the elements) with the highest density to cost ratio?

To point to an application, say that my goal was to mass produce a solid 1 meter cube for consumers and I wanted to make it as heavy as possible, for as cheap as possible. What is the best material choice?

Now, sort your list based on their associated negative environmental impacts (from most to least impacting). Please include your reasoning/sources for the top 1 or 2 materials in your list.

Factors to be considered when gauging environmental impact: How invasive/disruptive/polluting are the material's acquisition, production, or disposal methods.

I referenced this [***material density chart***](http://www.psyclops.com/tools/technotes/materials/density.html) which listed elements mostly (not many materials) and found that Iridium is the densest element w/ d=22650kg/m^3 (i.e., the weight of our cube would be 22650kg). The best [***cost chart***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prices_of_elements_and_their_compounds) that I could find was on wiki, which stated that the current cost of Iridium is 42000/kg which brings the material cost of our cube to $951.3E6!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about prices rather than physics.

Comment: It is about prices that DEPEND on physics.. Do you not agree that resolving this question might help someone someday?

Comment: @Landon - It is the kind of information which one might conceivably find in a table in an introductory book on materials science & engineering, but not in a physics book.

Comment: The foundation of material science & engineering is physics.

Comment: @Landon Don't worry, if your question was closed on a site, you are free to re-post it on another. This time, maybe https://engineering.stackexchange.com would be an ideal target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use any waste, as its cost is zero (furthermore, people can pay you to get rid of their waste), so you can make your "figure of merit" infinite:-)

Comment: Haha I now see you posted this a min before I submitted my second comment to peterh's answer.. I agree that some type of waste material is probably going to be the winner (most likely it will be concrete), but I would still like to know if there are any with a higher density than concrete's 5000 kg/m^3! The issue however is that I don't know where to look for this information. Waste material data seems hard to come by...

Comment: Which is why the cost of the counterweight is more about transportation and molding.

Answer (score 1):

Cranes are using concrete as counterweight:

[image]

Typically the transport costs are also considered.

If we allow fluids, then the answer is probably water.

Comment: Good thinking! Depending on the process/composition used, concrete can have density 2000~5000 kg/m^3. It is abundant/cheap, can be acquired by recycling ruble, could be close to pollution free if produced correctly, and if it were ever discarded it wouldn't really harm the environment (other than just taking up space)...

Comment: This gives me an idea... maybe there are other waste materials with higher density than concrete! However, I can't find any good info regarding this, the only source I could find was:
https://www.epa.vic.gov.au/business-and-industry/lower-your-impact/~/media/Files/bus/EREP/docs/wastematerials-densities-data.pdf